# Tomcat Spring can not realize the path of the file even the path has been added to servlet.xml and HomeController.java file?

Tags: java, spring, tomcat

I am newbie with Java Spring and making a very simple program with Spring.

I decided to put my web.xml, demo-config.servet.xml and some folders and xml files into one path to make it to be clear.

Then, I updated the HomeController.java file :

```
package DemoSpringMVC.Controller;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
@Controller
public class HomeController {
@RequestMapping("/")
public String Index() {
    return "user/index";
}
}
```

and I updated the demo-config-servlet.xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.3.xsd">
<context:component-scan
    base-package="DemoSpringMVC"></context:component-scan>
    <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/"></property>
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp"></property>
    </bean>
    </beans>
```

The eclipse shows no error, so I thought that I have no error.

But when I ran my DemoSpringMVC, it show me that the link is inactive ? As you can see in this picture ?

[image: My problem]

Here is my code, if you need to reference

```
https://github.com/nguyencuc2586/Spring3.1
```

Could you please give me some advices ? Thank you in advance.

Comment: What is tomcat version where you are deploying this application? As you are using the servlet API > 4.0 you need tomcat 9.0. If you are not using 9.0 try it once and let me know the result.

Comment: @KunalVarpe I am using Tomcat v10.0, should I delete it and reinstall it again ?

Comment: No if you are using the version greater than 9.0 then it would be fine. Can you create complete minimal project which can run deploy and reproduces the issue?

Comment: @KunalVarpe thanks for your comment. I think the problem is because of the Tomcat v10.0, because when I delete it and reinstall Tomcat v9.0.62, my code ran ok with no problem.

Comment: Can you please double check the URL you're hitting? If your war file is named something else, you need to map URL accordingly. See if it's http://localhost:8080/DemoSpringMVC-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/

Answer (score -1):

As per your code you are using servlet API 4.0 which needs Tomcat 9.0 and you mentioned that you are using Tomcat 10, so try using the Tomcat 9.0+ version.